# Is there a way to run a video/audio call in the background using the Flutter Twilio Programmable Video plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio-api, videocall

I'm creating a Flutter app and I want to integrate audio/video call functionality using the Flutter **[twilio_programmable_video](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video)** package. I want to be able to move the call process to the background so I can navigate through the app whilst still on the call.

Answer (score 1):

I could find the following on their [pub.dev page](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video):

> **Background Modes:** To allow a connection to a Room to be persisted while
> an application is running in the background, you must select the
> Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture background mode from the
> Capabilities project settings page. See Twilio Docs for more
> information.

This sounds a bit ambiguous, however, it should be possible, due to this GitLab issue / req I found: [Optimize running a video call in the background](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/issues/26).

So definitely give it a shot and follow the instructions on their pub.dev page - let me know if it worked.

Comment: I don't even think the issue pointed out there has been solved. I'll have to look for a workaround it myself. Will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: It is more like a proposal to do something on default whenever the app IS IN THE BACKGROUND, which in return means, that it is possible to run it in the background in the first place.

Comment: It's not the app i want to run in the background. I want to run the call on the background of the app, so I can navigate around the app. Just like Whatsapp does it.